# Powershell error when using CloudDrive Azure sample

Tags: powershell, azure, blob

I am currently trying to use the CloudDrive (Powershell) sample that comes with the Azure SDK to list the blobs I have stored. I'm getting an error fairly early in the process, and I figure there must be something I'm doing wrong - I just don't know how to debug this kind of problem...

I have followed a [great tutorial](http://blog.benday.com/archive/2008/11/07/23201.aspx) regarding logging, and also watched the ["How To" video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dd637760.aspx) and both of them breeze right past the area where I'm having trouble.

It seems pretty straight forward, you run the MountDrive Powershell script which by default will look at the development store on the local machine, and this script will mount two new drives for you, a Blob and a Queue drive.

Then you can just perform a "`dir Blob:`" or a "`dir Queue:`" and in the links above, the required information is shown. In my case, `dir Queue:` works just fine, but `dir Blob:` yields the following Powershell error:

```
....\Azure\samples\CloudDrive\scripts> dir Blob:
Get-ChildItem : The specified container name ".." is not valid!Please choose a name that conforms to the naming conventions for containers!
At line:1 char:4
+ dir <<<<  Blob:
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Now the "problem" container name being referred to above - ".." - looks suspiciously like the "dot" and "two dots" listed in any drive you may perform a "dir" operation on. I'm not sure it has anything to do with that, but in all online demos I've seen, people get a list of their Blob folders etc, I just get this error, and I don't know how to fix it.

Any help greatly appreciated...

Update: I am indeed using the Windows 7 RC with Powershell pre-installed. If this version is in fact buggy, then how do I go about getting a previous version on there...if at all possible?

Thanks,

Rob G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Windows 7 RC? If so, there are a couple of bugs in the version of powershell on that system that may prevent samples working correctly. I have used the blob provider successfully on Vista, so I'm sure the sample is fine.

-Oisin

Comment: Yes I'm using the windows 7 RC - Powershell comes installed already. If there are "a couple of bugs" - then how does one go about getting a better version?

Comment: You can't. Your best bet is to install Virtual XP (free with win7) and install powershell 2.0 CTP3 into the virtual environment. Win7 powershell is a system component, and can not be downgraded.

Comment: Many thanks for your help Oisin - very kind. P.S. I have no problems using GUI tools to look at my storage, I was mainly looking at the Powershell side for automation purposes. Thanks again...